# How do I get Intellij IDEA to auto-complete the type of an initialized variable?

Tags: intellij-idea

I write:

```
x = getFoo();
```

How can I get IDEA to turn this into:

```
Foo x = getFoo();
```

? IDEA certainly knows what the return type of `getFoo` is, but it refuses to auto-complete it.

[The documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html) says that `Ctrl+Shift+Space` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: broken link, I found this blog post https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/08/smart-type-completion-becomes-even-smarter/

Answer (score 11):

Use the [postfix code completion feature](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/) instead.  What you would write is `getFoo().var`, and this will auto-expand it to the type and let you modify the variable name.